# Understanding assignment when using rlang::eval_tidy

Tags: r, rlang, nse

I want to understand why the following happens when evaluating `<-` assignment operations using `rlang::eval_tidy`.

Let's use `rlang::expr` to create an expression to assign the variable `x` a value 1.

```
x_expr <- rlang::expr(x <- 1)
```

We also create an environment in which we want to evaluate the expression.

```
new_env <- new.env(parent = parent.env(environment()))
```

My intention is that we assign `1` to `x` inside `new_env`.

Now, we use `base::eval` to evaluate this expression:

```
eval(x_expr, envir = new_env)
get('x', envir = new_env)
```

This returns `1`. If we simply evaluate `x` in the global environment, we get an error (indicating `x` is in `new_env` and not taken from the global environment). 
We can remove `x` from `new_env`, and then re-assign it as we'd like using `rlang::eval_bare`:

```
rm('x', envir = new_env)
rlang::eval_bare(x_expr, env = new_env)
get('x', envir = new_env)
```

Again, this gives `1`.

Now, we remove `x` from `new_env` again, and try to re-assign it using `rlang::eval_tidy`. However, in this case we get an error when we look for `x` in `new_env`:

```
rm('x', envir = new_env)
rlang::eval_tidy(x_expr, env = new_env)
get('x', envir = new_env)
```

Why does this happen? I presume `x` has been assigned `1`, but where?

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_South Africa.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_South Africa.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_South Africa.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=English_South Africa.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0    yaml_2.2.1     rlang_0.4.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/eval_tidy.html) on `eval_tidy()`:

> `eval_tidy()` always evaluates in a data mask, even when data is `NULL`. Because of this, it has different stack semantics than `base::eval()`:
>
> - Lexical side effects, such as assignment with `<-`, occur in the mask rather than `env`.

We can confirm this by adding a data mask during `tidy_eval()`

```r
library(rlang)

x_expr <- rlang::expr(x <- 1)
new_env <- new.env(parent = parent.env(environment()))
data_mask <- rlang::new_data_mask(new.env(parent = parent.env(environment())))

rlang::eval_tidy(x_expr, data_mask, env = new_env)

get('x', envir = data_mask) ## Returns 1
```